# Regarding the Truth Table

Tags: digital-logic

My question is simple. Is it possible to have two outputs for the same inputs?

For example let A = input 1, B = input 2, C = output

```
ABC
110
111
001
000
```

Can this be applied? If so, how?

---

Addition:

The order of the 3-digit numbers is the same with the order of ABC so in the first 3-digit number, A = 1, B = 1, C = 0 and so on.

Comment: Your question is not *simple*, it's unclear. What does *ABC 110 111 001 000* mean? is it just a malformatted table? Where's there's multiple outputs in here ("C" is exactly one output, isn't it?) *Can this be applied?*: What, exactly, applied to what? Sorry, if you don't give a lot more context, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: hello actually that is supposed to be arranged vertically. i apologize.

Comment: That is only possible in a system with some sort of memory.

Comment: @Andrew Okay so how will that be?

Comment: Sure you can. Just like having multiple answers to the same question.

Comment: For sequential logic, yes; for combinational logic, no. Your truth table implies combinational logic as there's no clock signal.

Comment: No, you can not have two inputs represent a different logic result on a single output line. There ARE methods to change the function of a logic block, but you still need at least one more input to select the state. That extra signal could possibly be internal to the logic circuit if it is synchronous logic.

Answer (score 2):

Not on its own, you need some kind of memory like with a JK latch or additional input to differentiate when which output should happen.

In a JK latch the previous output is preserved if both inputs are 0 and the output is flipped when both are 1. This is achieved by internally by using the output as an additional input to keep the state.

J and K are the inputs Q is the output and L is the previous output.

```
JK Q
10 0
01 1
00 L
11 ~L
```

Comment: *"This is achieved by internally by using the output as an additional input to keep the state."* so effectively... NO.